# ¿Cómo hacer un trigger que sume dos campos y los almacene en otra tabla MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo dos tablas en MySql, la tabla mantenimientos y trabajos relacionadas de la siguiente manera:

mantenimientos ***1:M*** trabajos

En la tabla **mantenimientos** tengo el campo **valor_total**, y en la tabla trabajos tengo los campos **costo_manobra** y **costo_repuesto**. Me gustaría hacer un trigger que cada vez que inserte un nuevo registro en la tabla **trabajos** me sume los valos de **costo_manobra** y de **costo_repuestos** y el total me lo almacene en el campo **valor_total** de la tabla **mantenimientos**...

Yo hice una función que me suma los campos pero no sé si sea posible almacenar los resultados de una función en una tabla. La hice así:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `val_total`(id_mante BIGINT(20)) 
RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN
DECLARE result FLOAT(3.2);
SET result = (SELECT SUM(costo_repuestos) 
              FROM trabajos 
              WHERE mantenimiento_id = id_mante) 
              + 
             (SELECT SUM(costo_manobra) 
              FROM trabajos 
              WHERE mantenimiento_id = id_mante);
RETURN result;
END$$
```

Donde ***mantenimiento_id*** es la clave foránea de la tabla **trabajos** que la relaciona con la tabla **mantenimientos**...

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es crear un trigger en la tabla trabajos y utilizando un poco la lógica de tu función debería ser de la siguiente manera:

```sql
delimiter $$
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tg_sumar_costos AFTER INSERT ON trabajos FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @result = (SELECT SUM(costo_repuestos) FROM trabajos WHERE mantenimiento_id = NEW.mantenimiento_id) + (SELECT SUM(costo_manobra) FROM trabajos WHERE mantenimiento_id = NEW.mantenimiento_id);

    UPDATE mantenimientos SET valor_total= @result WHERE id= NEW.mantenimiento_id;
END;$$
```

El trigger se dispara después de cada insert en la tabla trabajos para que pueda sumar la el ingreso nuevo, eso lo definimos en `AFTER INSERT ON trabajos`.

Luego le decimos que se ejecute por cada fila insertada `FOR EACH ROW`.

Definimos una variable llamada `SET @result` para que almacene la suma de los trabajos segun tu logica definida en tu función. El `@` nos indica que estamos trabajando con una variable.

La variable `NEW` se crea cuando utilizamos trigger de `insert` o `update`, la cual hace referencia a los datos nuevos que se están ingresando en la tabla, contiene todas las columnas de tu tabla referida en el trigger.

Por ultimo actualizamos la tabla `mantenimientos` en la columna `valor_total` con el valor de la variable `@result`

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de utilizar **+**, utiliza un **INNER JOIN**

`CREATE TRIGGER trgTrb
ON DB_Nombre
AFTER insert, delete, update
AS`

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
BEGIN
    UPDATE     algo
    SET        members = (SELECT SUM(costo_repuestos) FROM trabajos WHERE mantenimiento_id = i.id_mante)
    FROM       inserted i
    INNER JOIN Artists algo
    ON         algo.id_mante = i.id_mante
END
ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM deleted)
BEGIN
    UPDATE     algo
    SET        members = (SELECT SUM(costo_manobra) FROM trabajos WHERE mantenimiento_id = d.id_mante)
    FROM       deleted d
    INNER JOIN Artists algo
    ON         algo.id_mante = d.id_mante
END
```

GO